# PyMongo: querying using json with a list

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

If I have some json like this:

```
query = {
   "canonical.operatingSystemFamily": "Linux",
   "canonical.region": "us-east-1"
}
```

I can pass that directly into find and it works:

```
self._db_conn[collection_name].find(query)
```

I want to do the same, but with lists, e.g.:

```
query = {
    "canonical.operatingSystemFamily": ["Linux","Windows"],
    "canonical.region": ["us-east-1", "us-east-2"]
}
```

Is there a way to do that? I know about "$in" but I do not want to have to parse my query data. This is a very simplified example, and there are a lot of fields that may or may not be there. Is there a way to use that json with lists directly?

Comment: You know about `$in` which is good.  You don't want to parse query data -- but how did you get `["Linux","Windows"]` attached to `canonical.operatingSystemFamily`?  That didn't come directly from the app did it?

Comment: JSON data types include lists, objects, strings, numbers and null. Also, you can always verify your query string in any JSON formatter / validator.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti it is part of a much larger data structure that comes from an external source. What I showed is a simplified example to show my question.  In the app the entire data structure is passed to find and it works except when there is a list in the data.

Comment: @prasad_ I know all about JSON. How does your reply help answer my question?

Comment: What are the types of the fields `"canonical.operatingSystemFamily"` and `"canonical.region"` ?

Comment: They are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not much of a parser - just checking `type`.

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.8.10 (default, May  4 2021, 00:00:00) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: query = {
   ...:     "canonical.operatingSystemFamily": ["Linux","Windows"],
   ...:     "canonical.region": ["us-east-1", "us-east-2"]
   ...: }

In [2]: for k,v in query.items():
   ...:     if type(v)==list:
   ...:         query[k]={"$in": v}
   ...: 

In [3]: query
Out[3]: 
{'canonical.operatingSystemFamily': {'$in': ['Linux', 'Windows']},
 'canonical.region': {'$in': ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2']}}
```

If you wanted, you could define a function to transform `query` when a `list` is present.

```py
from copy import deepcopy
def query_lfixer(query, copy=True):
    if copy:
        query = deepcopy(query)
    for k, v in query.items():
        if type(v)==list:
            query[k] = {"$in": v}
    return query
```

And then you could use it like:

```py
self._db_conn[collection_name].find(query_lfixer(query))
```

Or you could transform `query` in any number of other ways too.

Comment: This is part of a much larger data structure that comes from an external source. What I showed is a simplified example to show my question. In the app the entire data structure is passed to find and it works except when there is a list in the data.

Comment: @LarryMartell  This will work on an arbitrarily large input `query` and convert any list to an `$in` expression.   Should do the trick.

Comment: @LarryMartell All this does is modify the `query` you showed so that `list`'s would use `{"$in" ...`.  All other field types are untouched.

Comment: Currently the code does this: `self._db_conn[collection_name].find(query)` If I use the code above how would I pass in both the query and the $in clause?

Comment: @LarryMartell There are lots of possibilities.  I updated my answer with one way someone could do it.

Comment: @LarryMartell I updated the function definition so that it copies `query` by default.  The `copy` is only shallow so if there are deeply nested objects, the references may point to the same underlying objects.  Use the function with caution and maybe even write your own to insure data integrity where you need it.  I can't know what your needs are.

Comment: @LarryMartell I changed `copy` to `deepcopy` so that the original `query` used as an argument to `query_lfixer` will remain intact.  The function now will only return the modified `query` and not affect the original `query`.  Of course, program as you see fit.  I just didn't want someone to copy/paste the function and then wonder what happened to their original `query`.  If someone doesn't care, or perfers, they can call the function like `query_lfixer(query, copy=False)`.